# Help Identifying Non-Standard USB Connector

Tags: usb, connector, identification

I need help in identifying a part and finding a source (if possible) for a non-standard USB connector... at least I believe it to be non-standard. I've attached a few pictures which are focused to the best of my abilities.

The connector measures approximately .200" x .085" and has 8 positions. The 6 inner most positions are recessed maybe .030" further back than the two outside positions. This particular connector mates with a Nikon camera. It seems to be for USB and AV.

Any thoughts?

[image: Connector Front]
[image: Connector Top]

Comment: "The 6 inner most positions are recessed maybe .030" further back than the two outside positions." The outer two pins will be power supply, it allows hot plugging the device because it ensures power is attached before any signals. Many semiconductors act like a thyristor while signals are applied before power, ultimately killing the chip in worst case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called a UC-E6 cable. It looks to be non-standard enough that I can't find anywhere that sells the connectors, but it is pretty easy to find the cable.

Comment: Though I was never able to find a source for the connector... this is indeed the correct call out.